# Find out whats taking up space in a program Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, uninstall, storage

On the uninstall or change a program window in control panel, a program is supposedly taking up 1.23TB of space which can't be right. I'd uninstall this but am worried that it will delete other files that aren't associated.

How can I figure out what's taking up this space so I can decide whether or not to remove or move it?
[image]

Note that this also displays the same in the new Windows 10 settings screen.

Let me know if any extra info is required!

Comment: [Question. Download size. :: Age of Empires® III: Complete Collection General Discussions](https://steamcommunity.com/app/105450/discussions/0/492378806382333815/) - size 4GB

Comment: Try this really good old friend: https://windirstat.net/

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20040709-00/?p=38493 may help.  Essentially it's up to the developer to provide a value, if not it will be calculated.  I assume it's the same in all versions of Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Steam page for
[Age of Empires® III: Complete Collection](https://store.steampowered.com/app/105450/Age_of_Empires_III_Complete_Collection/)
says this :

> **System Requirements**
>   ...
>   Hard Drive:12 GB HD space

So either you have created or loaded an enormous map(s) or saved thousands of games,
or you have a problem with the disk.

The first possibility you can fix without my help.
You may use a program such as
[JDiskReport](http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/)
to find out where is the wasted space.
You may need to uninstall the game to get rid of it in an orderly manner.

For the second possibility, I suggest :

1. Download and install
   [Speccy](https://www.ccleaner.com/speccy)
   and verify the S.M.A.R.T. data of the disk.
   If Speccy signals errors, the disk itself may need replacing.
   If no errors, continue on.
2. Take a complete backup of all your data.
   If possible, take a backup disk image on an external disk with a tool such as
   [AOMEI Backupper Standard Freeware](https://www.backup-utility.com/free-backup-software.html) - a success here is a positive sign.
   [Create Bootable CD/DVD or USB Flash Drive Based on Windows PE](https://www.backup-utility.com/features/create-bootable-disc.html),
   and boot it and verify that AOMEI Backupper can see its backup on the external disk, just in case.
3. In an elevated Command Prompt (cmd), run the command :

   ```
   chkdsk C:      (assuming this is on the C drive)
   ```
4. If any errors are found, beware - you have problems.
   Run next, to fix the errors :

   ```
   chkdsk /f C:
   ```
5. If the errors are fixed, check again if Age of Empires disk space is now
   normal.
   If normal : Verify that it still works and if not then uninstall
   and reinstall it.
   If still enormous : Uninstall it and run chkdsk again.
6. If the errors are not fixed, cross your fingers and run :

   ```
   chkdsk /f /r C:
   ```
7. If nothing helps and the disk is still showing errors,
   reformat it (slow - not quick format) and reinstall everything including
   Windows and all applications.
   If it still shows problems, replace it.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer, I'll accept if it helps when I have another look